# Why does using one cell in Exact formula in excel works, but when i am using the whole range it does not?

Tags: excel

|orange|orange|
|apple |apple |
|banana|banana|
|melon |melon |

formula =exact does not work if it is like this =EXACT($A$1,$B$1:$B$4), but works if it is like this =EXACT (A1,B1), i have over 50 000 data so i need it to work with the whole range, i have tried putting {} at the start and at the end, it does not work like that neither

Answer (score 0):

It works in array form, as follow:

```
=EXACT(A1:A3,B1)
```

or using the array in the second input argument:

```
=EXACT(B1,A1:A3)
```

[image: excel output]

Comment: Perhaps the OP doesn't have 0365?